# Sulu Search doesn't return anything

Tags: symfony, content-management-system, sulu

I implemented the Sulu default Search in my project. It doesn't return anything.
When i try to reindex things on the console I get the following error:

```
Error indexing or de-indexing page (path: .../contents/ueber-uns/team, locale: de): There is no search mapping for object with class "Sulu\Component\Content\Compat\Structure\PageBridge"
```

Comment: Have you used the default configuration? And which Sulu version do you use?

Comment: yes. we used the default config and it was the latest version from friday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the old `sulu:search:reindex-content` command is still on this branch, which cannot be used anymore. It will be removed in future versions, you have to remember to use the `massive:search:index:rebuild` command.